# Logback Groovy SiftingAppender Configuration

Tags: groovy, logback, logback-groovy

Is it possible to configure a SiftingAppender via groovy(logback.groovy)? And how? I have seen many posts about configuring it via XML but not with groovy

Thanks

Comment: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender has some config with a "View as Groovy" link.  Can't get it to load atm, but YMMV?

Comment: Actually, http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html#sift says: _"SINCE VERSION 1.0.12 SiftingAppender is no longer supported within groovy configuration files. However, in case there is demand, it may be re-introduced."_

Comment: @tim_yates. I noticed that to be honest, so does that means that we should generally prefer xml over groovy? why some things are not supported in groovy version (which it is very convenient) and how I can find a comparison table or something? Thank you

Comment: Best I can see is a JIRA issue here: http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-957 But again, I can't get that page to load at the moment :-/